# Why does perl remove the file extension when redirecting url via CMD?

Tags: perl, url

I am at age 13 attempting to learn Perl. Here is one of my first scripts. The link brings the user to a webpage which downloads an image. As some observant people may notice the link has the ending of .png which specifies the image in the url. When I run this script it opens Chrome, opens the url BUT fails to include the extension .png . My questions are:

A) Why is this happening?
B) Can anyone suggest an alternative and or fix my script.

The script is found here below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Type Username Here:
";

$username = <>;

print "Link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png
";

exec "start www.s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png";
```

Please help!!!

Comment: If you want a newline in a string literal, use `\n`; don't split the string literal across lines.

Comment: And don't feed raw user input to `exec`. On Unix, imagine what happens if `$username` is `"; rm -rf $HOME ;"`; I'm sure there's an equivalent on Windows. (Do *not* try this!)

Answer (score 4):

When you capture the data, you are also capturing the new line at the end of it.

This gives you:

```
exec "start www.s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/EXAMPLE
.png";
```

Remove the whitespace from the end of the entered data to avoid this.

```
$username =~ s/\s+$//;
```

or

```
chomp($username);
```

Answer (score 3):

`$username` will include the carriage-return you hit when you hit "enter" at the input prompt, so your exec call actually looks like two separate commands:

```
start www.s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username
.png
```

Try `chomp($username)` to strip off that whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You have to whipe the *newline* at end of your input:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Type Username Here:
";

chomp ( $username = <> );

print "Link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png
";

exec "start www.s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png";
```

You could *sanitize* (ensure that user input contain only letters, numbers and/or the character underscore `_`, for sample) you variable by:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Type Username Here:
";

$username = $1 if <> =~ /^([a-z0-9_]*)$/i;

print "Link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png
";

exec "start www.s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png";
```

Better written (as @KeithThompson comment):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Type Username Here:
";

if ( <> =~ /^([a-z0-9_]*)$/i ) {

    $username = $1
    print "Link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png\n";

    exec "start www.s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/$username.png";
} else {

    print "Error input contain invalid characters\n";

};
```

Comment: That will leave `$username` undefined if the input doesn't match. You need to check whether it matches and take some other action (such as dying with an error message) if it doesn't.